How do I fix this hydration error in my next js layout file
I am getting a hydration error in my Next js layout.tsx file. I think it is the Footer component.
I have trying to edit the footer component. I do not if I am coding layout file in a wrong way. Or adding the component in a  different
way.


import type { Metadata } from "next";
import {inter} from '@/ui/fonts';
import   '@/styles/globals.css'
import Navbar from "@/ui/componets/Navbar";
import Footer from "@/ui/componets/Footer";



export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: " Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
     
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>

  );
}




The code you provided is of no use since the Footer component is emitting the hydration error, you must at least provide the Footer component and the error message so that we can help, your question lacks information.
Also if you have hydration problem you might want to read this page in nextjs docs
